# FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Program Files\jvm.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp, jvm, filenotfounderror

I run this code

```
import ctypes 
ctypes.CDLL('C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_271\bin\client\jvm.dll')
ZEMBEREK_PATH = r'C:\Users\ftufan\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\zemberek'
startJVM(getDefaultJVMPath(), '-ea', '-Djava.class.path=%s' % (ZEMBEREK_PATH))
```

and i get this error

FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_27in\client\jvm.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

How can i solve this?

Comment: try to prefix `dll` path with `r`.